# how to change template of content block?

Tags: xml, blocks

I am trying to change content blocks template, but I couldn't.

My `xml` is:

```
<reference name="content">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/template.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

what is wrong with this xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant call `setTemplate` method on `content` block.`content` block is of type `core/text_list`.modify your code like this.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="{YOUR_BLOCK_NAME}" template="template.phtml />
</reference>
```

you should call this block with `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("{YOUR_BLOCK_NAME}")` . or you can add `ouput="toHtml"` to the block defintion.like this.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="core/template" name="{YOUR_BLOCK_NAME}" template="template.phtml output="toHtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: Whats the use of `output="toHtml"`?

Comment: if you use `output="toHtml`. you dont have to call this block from phtml file.